# Android Nested Fragments or Simple Layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-adapter

I'm extremely new to java and coding for Android (new to programming in general). I haven't programmed much before so I wasn't able to think about this and whether or not I'd be able to implement when I first started designing this app. I would really appreciate some help or guidance, or at least pointers. I'm sorry if this is a really stupid question and thanks in advance for all answers.

[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLrAY.png)

Here is a mockup of the layout I want to create. It mainly cosists of a List, which displays information and images. (Should be `ScrollView` so that it can go up and down?)

Below is a button which will send information to another `Fragment` or `Activity`.

Both these layouts need to be part of an `ImageView`, able to be swiped left and right. Also need to add circle indicators (I've seen libraries that are capable of helping me achieve this)

There is also a Navigation Drawer at the top left which I will try to use `RecyclerView` with.

And lastly, there is a bottom navigation bar, which I'm currently able to do by using a library from [com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1](http://com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1') and navigating between different `Fragments`.

Please give me some advice on what to do or some pointers on how I might go about creating this sort of layout.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello & Welcome. Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - We're here to help you with specific programming problems, not to write code for you. Please show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts with us and we'll help you find a solution, but nobody is going to write code for you. According to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) your question is actually Off-Topic to Stackoverflow. I ask you to edit your question according to our guidelines, otherwise you won't get that much help

Comment: @YagamiLight Hello, thank a lot for your comment. Sorry for the confusion but I am a total newbie to this site and also programming. how would you suggest I improve my question? I have a lot to ask but I didn't want to create so many questions because it would become annoying for everyone. I guess if I had to ask one question, it would be: should i use nested fragments to do what I have in my mockup.png or use many different viewers such as ListView and ImageView

Comment: It's totally normal to get confused first time in SO, to improve your question simplly try something with your own skills (in programming) after that add to your question what you try so far and i am sure they will replay to your question. good luck